# PDF output with correct spaces in code examples

Tags: pdf, conversion, markdown, restructuredtext

I have been using `rst2pdf` and `pandoc` to convert the following reStructuredText into PDF:

```
This is a python example::

  def main():
      print("Hello World!")

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()

And one for YAML::

   server:
      name: ts0
      location: paris
```

although the two programs use a different engine to generate PDF (`pandoc` even requires you to install TeX for that) the result is a PDF  file, from which you cannot correctly cut-and-paste code examples:

[image]

The highlighted code (green background) is missing spaces because the empty spaces are generated in these PDF files with offsets.

Copy and paste results in ugly formatted code for many languages, but for programming languages like Occam and Python and for configuration files in YAML, this actually changes the meaning. If you are lucky that actually breaks things and you notice, but the YAML example e.g. is also correct without the spaces at the beginning of the line, it just has a different meaning.

This space-mangling-in-code-examples also happens in the PDF documents generated by the readthedocs site.

---

If you take the output from:

```
pandoc example.rst -o example.epub
```

and view the resulting one page file, you can copy and paste the code correctly. If you convert that `example.epub` with calibre (version 2.55.0) via its user-interface you get a PDF file from which you **can** correctly copy the code (with spaces), but the resulting PDF consists of 3 pages.

Trying to convert from the command line:

```
ebook-convert example.epub example.pdf
```

results in a rendering exception, adding the `--old-pdf-engine` option the conversion works, but you still have a 3 page PDF instead of a single page.

Converting via HTML:

```
rst2html example.rst > example.html; ebook-convert example.html example.pdf
pandoc example.rst -o example.html; ebook-convert example.html example.pdf
```

gives you correclty selectable code:

[image]

, but when pasting there are no spaces for the indent, and even the space between `Hello` and `World` disappears. Apart from that on larger files you get pagebreaks at unwanted places and the layout would need extensive tweaking via style sheets.

I tried conversion via `.odt` but that ended up in PDF files with completely unselectable text.

---

Given the following requirements for the PDF output:

- code fragments correctly selectable with spaces
- results similar in layout to that of `rst2pdf` or `readthedocs`

are there any command line tools to generate a PDF file, starting with a `.rst` file or some other mark-up format?

Comment: Anthon [reported this issue upstream](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf/issues/563), there might end up being a resolution there.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks for reminding me, I had forgotten about that %-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pipeline

**txttopdf.sh:**

```
enscript -B -p- | ps2pdf -dCompressPages=false - -
```

to generate a PDF which preserves the leading spacing of the source. The special `ps2pdf` option makes it use the content portion of the intermediate PostScript verbatim, leaving well indented text objects in the PDF. You can verify that by opening it with a plain text editor; the content portion is somewhere towards the end.

However, then it still depends on the PDF viewer whether it discards those leading spaces or not. E.g., `evince` as well as old `acroread` do, and they don't let me select the leading whitespace in the viewer. This is the same also if I replace the spaces with non-breaking space (of ISO-8859-1).

Thus, the pipeline does as much as you can do into the PDF file, and then you need to find a viewer that honours the spacing.

Comment: My `evince` doesn't have the `-B` option ( Linux Mint 17.3, i.e. latest). Also the output can be correct (although ugly) and doesn't depend on the reader, as the `ebook-convert` output shows.

Comment: Sorry; it should have been `enscript`, not `evince`. Anyhow, I need to check how the `ebook`  PDF file looks, then.

Comment: `enscript` just does the same as rst2pdf, but without the nice coloring of the code boxes. You can see the indent, but you cannot select them as spaces.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to figure out which PDF representation the viewer needs in order to allow the selection of leading spaces. How does the `ebook` output look; does it have a line including "Hello World"?

Comment: Yes of course it includes that line. I updated the question with how the output from `ebook-convert` looks for the small example, including how `evince` selects that.

Comment: RIght; would you be able to also paste in that selected portion of the PDF file as text? Unless it's compressed of course... my Debian Jessie doesn't have calibre 2.55.0 (only 2.5.0, without html plugin), and I don't want to mess it up, so I'm setting up a new box for Mint...

Comment: Duh, don't bother. The `ebook-convert` output looks better selected, but when pasted is worse than the `rst2pdf` output: the space in `Hello World!` missing as well...

Comment: Right. I also found that adding spaces between words causes havoc in selecting text for `evince`. It seems the only way is to replace spaces with something else, then replace again after copying. This also has interesting effects: eg using 0xb4 for space in the PDF file comes back as duplets 0xc2 0xf7 from copy paste. No fun. I give up.